# bower install just says cached validate, but doesn't install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, progress-bar, bower

I am trying to install [progressbar.js](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) into my rails app.

I run bower install progressbar.js

And the terminal puts out:

```
bower progressbar.js#*          cached https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js.git#1.0.1
bower progressbar.js#*        validate 1.0.1 against https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js.git#*
```

The files are not put into the app. When I run bower list, it has:

`progressbar.js#1.0.1 extraneous`

How do I install this? Other times I run bower install, it has worked no problem.

Comment: Do you use bower directly without any gem? I suggest you to use a wrapper like [bower-rails](https://github.com/rharriso/bower-rails)